# Vue.js build, config not gettign loaded when running on buildtest server

Tags: typescript, vue.js, iis

I have a vue 2 project

In my router\index.ts I have the following line

Vue.prototype.$config = require('/public/config.json')

The file has settings I need for init'ing Okta.

Work on my local box where public is at the same level as src.

When the build server creates a build, and copies it to the build server.

The config.json file (and all else in public) is in the root and the compiled code appears to be in the JS folder.

but the app doesn't load it, the values don't get used.

I tried moving it to a public folder off the root.

I tried moving it to a js\public folder.

Neither worked

Where do I have to move it to so that when the vue app gets loaded in IIS, it's going to load the values from the config.json file?`enter code here`.

As near as I can tell there is a version of the config.js from the app compiled into the js folder(it's loading settings from my dev box/source contorl, not failing to find the settings). Do I have to modify the build not to do that?

Comment: Can you access the production file from a browser? like `https://somewhere.com/config.json`?

Comment: Yes i totally can and it's the new "on the dev server" version, as it should be, but it not loaded. same for https://myApp.myserver.org/public/config.json

Answer (score 1):

I have the following ideas to solve your problem.

**FIRST:** You have to set the correct path to avoid a false reference with a relative or absolute path. In your case it would be something like:

```
Vue.prototype.$config = require(process.env.BASE_URL + '/public/config.json')
```

See the documentation for further information: [The public folder](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#the-public-folder)

---

**SECOND:** Move your `config.json` and refer to it from `src`. This would look like:

```
Vue.prototype.$config = require('~@/json/config.json')
```

Comment: Will this Lazy load it? The issue seems to be the file value is getting compiled in, not loaded at run time, thanks!

Comment: @EricBrown-Cal As far as I know, everything get's compiled. Only files in `public` will stay uncompiled.